# Develop Gmail Contextual Gadget without Google App domain?

Tags: gmail, google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I'm looking into creating a Gmail Contextual Gadget.  I've created a couple of simple gadgets that integrate into Google Calendar, and it was simple enough with those to publish the gadget manifest and add them to the calendar through the "add any gadget" labs feature.

The Gmail Contextual Gadget is starting to look like a different beast altogether (much more difficult to get up and running with a sample).  Do I really have to register a domain with Google Apps, submit an Application Manifest, etc. in order to simply try my hand at creating one of these gadgets?  Is there a simpler, less committal way of trying out the technology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES , you must have a Google Apps domain setup. It does not work for standard GMAIL accounts.